# Changing date in C string

Tags: c

I need to change date like "25 april 1889" (or "25 апреля 1889" in Russian) in "25/04/1889".
I have a function for changing date in struct, but gcc print that wcsptime() has implicit declaration (I included `<wchar.h>` and `<time.h>`):

```
void change_date(text_s *text, int numb_of_str, int beg_of_word, int length_month){
    wchar_t *temp = malloc(20 * sizeof(wchar_t));
    const int length_start = 8 + length_month;
    wcsncpy(temp, &text->sent[numb_of_str].str[beg_of_word], length_start);
    temp[length_start - 1] = L'\0';
    struct tm new_time;
    wcsptime(temp, L"%d %B %Y", new_time);
}
```

Are any ways how it possible to convert this date to needful format? Using struct tm and standart functions?
Struct of the change "text" looks like that:

```
typedef struct Sentense{
    long int length;
    wchar_t *str;
} sentense_s;

typedef struct Text{
    long int quant;
    sentense_s *sent;
} text_s;
```

Comment: Your question is not quite clear. Do you want to convert `25 april 1889` to `25/04/1889`?

Comment: Yes, I want it. Problem is that this date can be in other text.

Comment: `this date can be in other text` What do you mean by  other text?

Comment: For example: "It happend in 25 april 1889 so far from city". I mean,  that it's not only date in string.

Comment: What is *`text_s`*? Are you really dealing with wide strings? // edit: oh, yes, you are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason your code doesn't compile is because `wcsptime()` is not part of the C Standard Library. However, in your particular case it's relatively easy to implement (and you said you wanted to stick with the standard library):

```
int wstr_to_tm(const wchar_t* str, struct tm* tm)
{
    wchar_t mon[64];
    int i;
    static const wchar_t *months[] = { 
        L"Jan", L"Feb", L"Mar", L"Apr", L"May", L"Jun", 
        L"Jul", L"Aug", L"Sep", L"Oct", L"Nov", L"Dec" 
    };
    if(wcslen(str) > sizeof(mon)/2) return 0;
    if(swscanf(str, L"%u %ls %u", &tm->tm_mday, mon, &tm->tm_year) != 3)
        return 0;
    for(i = 0; i < 12; ++i)
    {
        if(wcsncmp(months[i], mon, wcslen(months[i])) == 0)
        {
            tm->tm_mon = i;
            break;
        }

    }
    return tm->tm_mon >= 0;
}
```

To convert to the string format you want, you would then do something like:

```
wchar_t* date = L"12 Oct 1966";
struct tm tm = {0};
if(wstr_to_tm(date, &tm))
    wprintf(L"%d/%d/%d\n", tm.tm_mday, tm.tm_mon, tm.tm_year);
```

You will need to add the month names in Russian and whatever other languages you need to support and then do the comparison based on the current locale.